# pip install libyang fails with exit code 2

Tags: python, yang

Trying to install libyang but it gives me this error:

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

I tried to uninstall and re install Visual studio build tools but it doesn't seems to work.

Here is the full output:

```
U:\>pip install libyang
Looking in indexes: https://censored/api/pypi/pythonproxy/simple
Collecting libyang
  Using cached https://censored/api/pypi/pythonproxy/packages/packages/75/83/ef8afc344f6454a0d80cf2acae677a28de06150acb6084d55c6a71194408/libyang-2.8.0.tar.gz (55 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cffi in c:\users\censored\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from libyang) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\censored\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cffi->libyang) (2.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: libyang
  Building wheel for libyang (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for libyang (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\context.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\keyed_list.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\schema.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\xpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      running egg_info
      writing libyang.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to libyang.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to libyang.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to libyang.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'libyang.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'libyang.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying libyang\VERSION -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      copying libyang\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\libyang
      running build_ext
      generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\\Release\\_libyang.c'
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      building '_libyang' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\censore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_libyang.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_libyang.obj -Werror -std=c99
      clÿ: Ligne de commande error D8021ÿ: argument num‚rique non valide '/Werror'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for libyang
Failed to build libyang
ERROR: Could not build wheels for libyang, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/libyang/ shows the only supported OS is Unix (see in the left column). The error message demonstrates the only supported compiler is `gcc`. The issue https://github.com/CESNET/libyang-python/issues/55 is still open, no code provided for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project maintainer has said Windows is not supported. https://github.com/CESNET/libyang-python/issues/55#issuecomment-1307364421

You can try to use WSL2 on your machine instead to get a Linux environment available